# Get children of a Tree-Structure recursively by using yield return

Tags: c#, tree, yield

I want to get a List of all Members in a Tree-like Structure (a Group which contains n groups which contain n groups and so on. The root Element also contains Members.

Schema:

```
Group
    Group
        Member
        Member
        Member
    Group
        Member
Group
    Member
    Member
Group
    Group
        Group
            Member
```

By now my code looks like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Member> GetMembers() {
     foreach(var member in this.MemberCollection) {
        yield return member;
     }
     foreach(var group in this.GroupCollection) {
        GetMembers();
     }
  }
```

Unfortunately this does not work - the "GetMembers()" call just gets "ignored" - is there a "Workaround"?

I already found solutions similar to this one:

```
public IEnumerable<Member> GetMembers() {
 foreach(var group in this.GroupCollection) {     
     foreach(var member in GetMembers()) {
         yield return member;
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with found solution?

Comment: Found solution looks working except the fact that it doesn't call `GetMembers()` on the current group. Maybe you should change it to `group.GetMembers()`.

Comment: Is `GetMembers` a method on the `Group` class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be recursive, your method should take a parameter (otherwise the recursion will never stop):

```
public IEnumerable<Member> GetMembers(Group group) {
     foreach(var member in group.MemberCollection) {
        yield return member;
     }
     foreach(var subGroup in group.GroupCollection) {
        foreach (var member in GetMembers(group)) {
            yield return member;
        }
     }
  }
```

However, recursive iterator blocks tend to be quite inefficient for deeply nested hierarchies. A better approach is to do use iteration rather than recursion. To get a depth-first traversal as in the recursive approach, you can do this:

```
public IEnumerable<Member> GetMembers() {
     var stack = new Stack<Group>();
     stack.Push(this);
     while (stack.Count > 0) {
         var group = stack.Pop();
         foreach(var member in group.MemberCollection) {
            yield return member;
         }
         foreach(var subGroup in group.GroupCollection) {
            stack.Push(subGroup);
         }
     }
  }
```

To get a breadth-first traversal, use a queue instead of a stack.

Comment: As `GetMembers()` is a method on `Group`you don't *need* to pass the reference to the group into the method, as it'd be a synonym for the `this` pointer

Answer (score 1):

Simply calling `GetMembers` isn't going to return its result from the calling method, and if it's not enumerated (and it uses `yield`), it's not going to appear to be called either, instead you could do something like:

```
public IEnumerable<Member> GetMembers() {
     foreach(var member in this.MemberCollection) {
        yield return member;
     }
     foreach(var group in this.GroupCollection) {
         foreach(var member in group.GetMembers()) {
            yield return member;
        }
    }
}
```

When you use `yield` in a method, the compiler actually generates a separate class that implemets `IEnumerable<>` to return your result - the class only emumerates lazily, so if you don't actually iterate the result, they are not evaluated (and also not evaluated *until* you enumerate them, if you're relying on state of a property that may be mutated elsewhere)

Comment: Yes that looks like a gool solution but you call `GetMembers()` for each contained group. I don't think that it will return separate values. In this case you can remove the foreach loop.

Comment: The problem is that the recursion will never end, since `this` is always the same.

Comment: Thanks, this finally solved my issue. If you've got some time, may it's possible for you to explain, why the GetMembers method gets ignored? So can I assume that a method that uses yield return isn't able to call another Method that uses yield return?

Comment: Have updated to expand on why using `yield` gives this behaviour; @ThomasLevesque just saw I missed the reference there; also fixed that.